# IPN Paypal (PHP)

Tags: php, database, paypal, connection, paypal-ipn

I have a serious problem that has been 'eating' my head inside out and which I can't seem to be able to solve.

I've made a IPN Listener and put it up on my website @ http://5.189.137.99/ipnlistener.php

the listener is a class, so i have another file, called ipn.php that has the functions needed when I get the payment notification and which also incorporates the IPNListener.

But when I go to the paypal sandbox, and try to use IPN Simulator, it constantly says that it's not able to connect to the url.

I'll leave my ipn listener code in here if anyone wants to take a look.

Even more weird is that when I try this other paypal website: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/applications/ipn_simulator
it says that the IPN was sucesfully sent, yet I didn't receive anything new in the Transaction tab.

```
<?php

class IpnListener {

    public $use_curl = true;     

    public $force_ssl_v3 = false;     

    /**
     *  If true, an SSL secure connection (port 443) is used for the post back 
     *  as recommended by PayPal. If false, a standard HTTP (port 80) connection
     *  is used. Default true.
     *
     *  @var boolean
     */
    public $use_ssl = true;      

    /**
     *  If true, the paypal sandbox URI www.sandbox.paypal.com is used for the
     *  post back. If false, the live URI www.paypal.com is used. Default false.
     *
     *  @var boolean
     */
    public $use_sandbox = false; 

    /**
     *  The amount of time, in seconds, to wait for the PayPal server to respond
     *  before timing out. Default 30 seconds.
     *
     *  @var int
     */
    public $timeout = 30;       

    private $post_data = array();
    private $post_uri = '';     
    private $response_status = '';
    private $response = '';

    const PAYPAL_HOST = 'www.paypal.com';
    const SANDBOX_HOST = 'www.sandbox.paypal.com';

    /**
     *  Post Back Using cURL
     *
     *  Sends the post back to PayPal using the cURL library. Called by
     *  the processIpn() method if the use_curl property is true. Throws an
     *  exception if the post fails. Populates the response, response_status,
     *  and post_uri properties on success.
     *
     *  @param  string  The post data as a URL encoded string
     */
    protected function curlPost($encoded_data) {

        if ($this->use_ssl) {
            $uri = 'https://'.$this->getPaypalHost().'/cgi-bin/webscr';
            $this->post_uri = $uri;
        } else {
            $uri = 'http://'.$this->getPaypalHost().'/cgi-bin/webscr';
            $this->post_uri = $uri;
        }

        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $uri);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $encoded_data);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $this->timeout);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);

        if ($this->force_ssl_v3) {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
        }

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

        $this->response = curl_exec($ch);
        $this->response_status = strval(curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE));

        if ($this->response === false || $this->response_status == '0') {
            $errno = curl_errno($ch);
            $errstr = curl_error($ch);
            throw new Exception("cURL error: [$errno] $errstr");
        }
    }

    /**
     *  Post Back Using fsockopen()
     *
     *  Sends the post back to PayPal using the fsockopen() function. Called by
     *  the processIpn() method if the use_curl property is false. Throws an
     *  exception if the post fails. Populates the response, response_status,
     *  and post_uri properties on success.
     *
     *  @param  string  The post data as a URL encoded string
     */
    protected function fsockPost($encoded_data) {

        if ($this->use_ssl) {
            $uri = 'ssl://'.$this->getPaypalHost();
            $port = '443';
            $this->post_uri = $uri.'/cgi-bin/webscr';
        } else {
            $uri = $this->getPaypalHost(); // no "http://" in call to fsockopen()
            $port = '80';
            $this->post_uri = 'http://'.$uri.'/cgi-bin/webscr';
        }

        $fp = fsockopen($uri, $port, $errno, $errstr, $this->timeout);

        if (!$fp) { 
            // fsockopen error
            throw new Exception("fsockopen error: [$errno] $errstr");
        } 

        $header .= "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";
        $header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
        $header .= "Content-Length: ".strlen($encoded_data)."\r\n";
        $header .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";

        fputs($fp, $header.$encoded_data."\r\n\r\n");

        while(!feof($fp)) { 
            if (empty($this->response)) {
                // extract HTTP status from first line
                $this->response .= $status = fgets($fp, 1024); 
                $this->response_status = trim(substr($status, 9, 4));
            } else {
                $this->response .= fgets($fp, 1024); 
            }
        } 

        fclose($fp);
    }

    private function getPaypalHost() {
        if ($this->use_sandbox) return IpnListener::SANDBOX_HOST;
        else return IpnListener::PAYPAL_HOST;
    }

    /**
     *  Get POST URI
     *
     *  Returns the URI that was used to send the post back to PayPal. This can
     *  be useful for troubleshooting connection problems. The default URI
     *  would be "ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com:443/cgi-bin/webscr"
     *
     *  @return string
     */
    public function getPostUri() {
        return $this->post_uri;
    }

    /**
     *  Get Response
     *
     *  Returns the entire response from PayPal as a string including all the
     *  HTTP headers.
     *
     *  @return string
     */
    public function getResponse() {
        return $this->response;
    }

    /**
     *  Get Response Status
     *
     *  Returns the HTTP response status code from PayPal. This should be "200"
     *  if the post back was successful. 
     *
     *  @return string
     */
    public function getResponseStatus() {
        return $this->response_status;
    }

    /**
     *  Get Text Report
     *
     *  Returns a report of the IPN transaction in plain text format. This is
     *  useful in emails to order processors and system administrators. Override
     *  this method in your own class to customize the report.
     *
     *  @return string
     */
    public function getTextReport() {

        $r = '';

        // date and POST url
        for ($i=0; $i<80; $i++) { $r .= '-'; }
        $r .= "\n[".date('m/d/Y g:i A').'] - '.$this->getPostUri();
        if ($this->use_curl) $r .= " (curl)\n";
        else $r .= " (fsockopen)\n";

        // HTTP Response
        for ($i=0; $i<80; $i++) { $r .= '-'; }
        $r .= "\n{$this->getResponse()}\n";

        // POST vars
        for ($i=0; $i<80; $i++) { $r .= '-'; }
        $r .= "\n";

        foreach ($this->post_data as $key => $value) {
            $r .= str_pad($key, 25)."$value\n";
        }
        $r .= "\n\n";

        return $r;
    }

    /**
     *  Process IPN
     *
     *  Handles the IPN post back to PayPal and parsing the response. Call this
     *  method from your IPN listener script. Returns true if the response came
     *  back as "VERIFIED", false if the response came back "INVALID", and 
     *  throws an exception if there is an error.
     *
     *  @param array
     *
     *  @return boolean
     */    
    public function processIpn($post_data=null) {

        $encoded_data = 'cmd=_notify-validate';

        if ($post_data === null) { 
            // use raw POST data 
            if (!empty($_POST)) {
                $this->post_data = $_POST;
                $encoded_data .= '&'.file_get_contents('php://input');
            } else {
                throw new Exception("No POST data found.");
            }
        } else { 
            // use provided data array
            $this->post_data = $post_data;

            foreach ($this->post_data as $key => $value) {
                $encoded_data .= "&$key=".urlencode($value);
            }
        }

        if ($this->use_curl) $this->curlPost($encoded_data); 
        else $this->fsockPost($encoded_data);

        if (strpos($this->response_status, '200') === false) {
            throw new Exception("Invalid response status: ".$this->response_status);
        }

        if (strpos($this->response, "VERIFIED") !== false) {
            return true;
        } elseif (strpos($this->response, "INVALID") !== false) {
            return false;
        } else {
            throw new Exception("Unexpected response from PayPal.");
        }
    }

    /**
     *  Require Post Method
     *
     *  Throws an exception and sets a HTTP 405 response header if the request
     *  method was not POST. 
     */    
    public function requirePostMethod() {
        // require POST requests
        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST') {
            header('Allow: POST', true, 405);
            throw new Exception("Invalid HTTP request method.");
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Are you able to see access requests to that file from within the access_log of your server? Also, I just tried to visit ipn.php (the file that you said calls your listener class), and it's come back with a Error 500.

Comment: If you follow the steps on [how to test PayPal IPN](https://www.angelleye.com/test-paypal-ipn/) you should be able to find your problem.

Comment: I have no idea why I can't acess ipn.php since I can acess all the other files, including the main website. I'll check that tutorial @AndrewAngell but it has been bugging my head..

Comment: I tried making a dummy ipn.php file with just 'hello world' and tried to acess it, and it worked. Also, when I try to acess it with www.domain.com/ipn.php , i get a blank page. How can I check my logs? I'm a begginer in all this and even in php, but I really need to get the IPN working :/ If someone could help me in more detail, I would be apprecited and thankful!

Comment: If you're getting a blank page that means there's a PHP error but you don't have error reporting enabled.  Add this to very the top of your IPN script:

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

Then follow the instructions in that how to guide on hitting the script directly.

Comment: do I add that to my ipn listener.php or my ipn.php (handler) my ipnlistener is working as a class, an i'm calling it in ipn.php to handle the result and if verified to change my database...

Comment: I did what you said but I got no errors shown in my browser? I re-made my listener and I confirmed it that it's working by using fwrite into a txt file of the result and the fields... now I think i just need something to do the stuff I want if $result == 'VERIFIED' ?

Comment: Thank you all! Got it working! I have another question, are TXN_ID's unique and never repeatable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a simple solution to the listener INP Paypal, I hope that helps you:

https://gist.github.com/ggwebdev/b2dec8bbd5635043d675#file-gistfile1-php

This code is based in: https://www.paypal-brasil.com.br/desenvolvedores/tutorial/recebendo-notificacoes-de-pagamento-instantaneo-ipn/ but more simple

Comment: I managed to code anothrt class which is fully working. Yhanks anyways!